# Match characters and numbers after //

Tags: regex

example string: a49x//3iiKZ4:3kk3l

I am trying to match everything between the // and : characters in the string above.  I can match the 4: part of it, but I can't match the the other characters because I can't figure out how to match the //.

Here is my existing Regular Expression:

[a-zA-Z0-9]:

If I enter // at the beginning, it fails.  I also tried //\ like this:

//[a-zA-Z0-9]:

How can I match this string so the values of

> 3iiKZ4

are returned? I don't want to return the // or : characters, only the characters between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape each of the slashes with backslashes, but you also need to add a * or + after your square brackets to ensure it captures one or more letters or numbers. The backslash to escape needs to come *before* the character that you're escaping, not after.

You can then enclose the square brackets within parentheses to capture the text as a group.

This should work for you: \/\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*):

$1 will be the group id that contains the string between the // and the :

Comment: That works perfect, but it also grabs the // and : which are outside of the values.  Is it possible to have this return everything inbetween the // :, but not return those actual characters?  They are just identifiers.

Comment: That works - thank you!  I have been trying for hours to fix it... ;)